# grpc route_guide_callback C++ example crashes

Tags: c++, grpc-c++

I try to build my own C++ application with grpc callback stream API, based on the grpc authors example:
/grpc/examples/cpp/route_guide/route_guide_callback_server.cc
and route_guide_callback_client.cc.

But the problem is, the example itself is buggy in part of bidirectional concept demonstration.
If you run the server to listen its port, and run clients one after another several times, randomly the server or the client crash.

I also noticed, that every next client is working longer and longer (its console output is longer and longer), and after some time one of them may tirgger server to crash.

The native source code has 4 objects, each for one of the concepts of grpc (unary, bidi etc.)
I copied the source code to here, in which the only "bidi" part is left unchanged, and the rest is removed, so that you could focus on the problematic code.

Do you have any suggestions, what might be wrong in it?

```
   #include <algorithm>
   #include <chrono>
   #include <cmath>
   #include <iostream>
   #include <memory>
   #include <string>
   #include <thread> 

  #include "helper.h"

  #include <grpc/grpc.h>
  #include <grpcpp/security/server_credentials.h>
  #include <grpcpp/server.h>
  #include <grpcpp/server_builder.h>
  #include <grpcpp/server_context.h>
  #ifdef BAZEL_BUILD
  #include "examples/protos/route_guide.grpc.pb.h"
  #else
  #include "route_guide.grpc.pb.h"
  #endif

  using grpc::CallbackServerContext;
  using grpc::Server;
  using grpc::ServerBuilder;
  using grpc::Status;
  using routeguide::Feature;
  using routeguide::Point;
  using routeguide::Rectangle;
  using routeguide::RouteGuide;
  using routeguide::RouteNote;
  using routeguide::RouteSummary;
  using std::chrono::system_clock;

  class RouteGuideImpl final : public RouteGuide::CallbackService {
   public:
    explicit RouteGuideImpl(const std::string& db) {
      routeguide::ParseDb(db, &feature_list_);
    }

    grpc::ServerBidiReactor<RouteNote, RouteNote>* RouteChat(
        CallbackServerContext* context) override {
      class Chatter : public grpc::ServerBidiReactor<RouteNote, RouteNote> {
       public:
        Chatter(absl::Mutex* mu, std::vector<RouteNote>* received_notes)
            : mu_(mu), received_notes_(received_notes) {
          StartRead(&note_);
        }

        void OnDone() override { delete this; }
        void OnReadDone(bool ok) override {
          if (ok) {
            // Unlike the other example in this directory that's not using
            // the reactor pattern, we can't grab a local lock to secure the
            // access to the notes vector, because the reactor will most likely
            // make us jump threads, so we'll have to use a different locking
            // strategy. We'll grab the lock locally to build a copy of the
            // list of nodes we're going to send, then we'll grab the lock
            // again to append the received note to the existing vector.
            mu_->Lock();
            std::copy_if(received_notes_->begin(), received_notes_->end(),
                         std::back_inserter(to_send_notes_),
                         [this](const RouteNote& note) {
                           return note.location().latitude() ==
                                      note_.location().latitude() &&
                                  note.location().longitude() ==
                                      note_.location().longitude();
                         });
            mu_->Unlock();
            notes_iterator_ = to_send_notes_.begin();
            NextWrite();
          } else {
            //std::cout << "some client finished" << std::endl;
            Finish(Status::OK);
          }
        }
        void OnWriteDone(bool ok) override 
        { 
          NextWrite();               
        }

       private:
        void NextWrite() {
          if (notes_iterator_ != to_send_notes_.end()) {
            StartWrite(&*notes_iterator_);
            notes_iterator_++;
          } else {
            mu_->Lock();
            received_notes_->push_back(note_);
            mu_->Unlock();
            StartRead(&note_);
          }
        }
        RouteNote note_;
        absl::Mutex* mu_;
        std::vector<RouteNote>* received_notes_;
        std::vector<RouteNote> to_send_notes_;
        std::vector<RouteNote>::iterator notes_iterator_;
      };
      return new Chatter(&mu_, &received_notes_);
    }

   private:
    std::vector<Feature> feature_list_;
    absl::Mutex mu_;
    std::vector<RouteNote> received_notes_ ABSL_GUARDED_BY(mu_);
  };

  void RunServer(const std::string& db_path) {
    std::string server_address("0.0.0.0:50051");
    RouteGuideImpl service(db_path);
  
    ServerBuilder builder;
    builder.AddListeningPort(server_address, grpc::InsecureServerCredentials());
    builder.RegisterService(&service);
    std::unique_ptr<Server> server(builder.BuildAndStart());
    std::cout << "Server listening on " << server_address << std::endl;
    server->Wait();
  }

  int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // Expect only arg: --db_path=path/to/route_guide_db.json.
    std::string db = routeguide::GetDbFileContent(argc, argv);
    RunServer(db);
  
    return 0;
  }
```

and the code of client:

```
  #include <chrono>
  #include <condition_variable>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <memory>
  #include <mutex>
  #include <random>
  #include <string>
  #include <thread>
  
  #include "helper.h"
  
  #include <grpc/grpc.h>
  #include <grpcpp/alarm.h>
  #include <grpcpp/channel.h>
  #include <grpcpp/client_context.h>
  #include <grpcpp/create_channel.h>
  #include <grpcpp/security/credentials.h>
  #ifdef BAZEL_BUILD
  #include "examples/protos/route_guide.grpc.pb.h"
  #else
  #include "route_guide.grpc.pb.h"
  #endif
  
  using grpc::Channel;
  using grpc::ClientContext;
  using grpc::Status;
  using routeguide::Feature;
  using routeguide::Point;
  using routeguide::Rectangle;
  using routeguide::RouteGuide;
  using routeguide::RouteNote;
  using routeguide::RouteSummary;
  
  Point MakePoint(long latitude, long longitude) {
    Point p;
    p.set_latitude(latitude);
    p.set_longitude(longitude);
    return p;
  }
  
  Feature MakeFeature(const std::string& name, long latitude, long longitude) {
    Feature f;
    f.set_name(name);
    f.mutable_location()->CopyFrom(MakePoint(latitude, longitude));
    return f;
  }
  
  RouteNote MakeRouteNote(const std::string& message, long latitude,
                          long longitude) {
    RouteNote n;
    n.set_message(message);
    n.mutable_location()->CopyFrom(MakePoint(latitude, longitude));
    return n;
  }
  
  class RouteGuideClient {
   public:
    RouteGuideClient(std::shared_ptr<Channel> channel, const std::string& db)
        : stub_(RouteGuide::NewStub(channel)) {
      routeguide::ParseDb(db, &feature_list_);
    }
  
    void RouteChat() {
      class Chatter : public grpc::ClientBidiReactor<RouteNote, RouteNote> {
       public:
        explicit Chatter(RouteGuide::Stub* stub)
            : notes_{MakeRouteNote("First message", 0, 0),
                     MakeRouteNote("Second message", 0, 1),
                     MakeRouteNote("Third message", 1, 0),
                     MakeRouteNote("Fourth message", 0, 0)},
              notes_iterator_(notes_.begin()) {
          stub->async()->RouteChat(&context_, this);
          NextWrite();
          StartRead(&server_note_);
          StartCall();
        }
        void OnWriteDone(bool /*ok*/) override { NextWrite(); }
        void OnReadDone(bool ok) override {
          if (ok) {
            std::cout << "Got message " << server_note_.message() << " at "
                      << server_note_.location().latitude() << ", "
                      << server_note_.location().longitude() << std::endl;
            StartRead(&server_note_);
          }
        }
        void OnDone(const Status& s) override {
          std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(mu_);
          status_ = s;
          done_ = true;
          cv_.notify_one();
        }
        Status Await() {
          std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(mu_);
          cv_.wait(l, [this] { return done_; });
          return std::move(status_);
        }
  
       private:
        void NextWrite() {
          if (notes_iterator_ != notes_.end()) {
            const auto& note = *notes_iterator_;
            std::cout << "Sending message " << note.message() << " at "
                      << note.location().latitude() << ", "
                      << note.location().longitude() << std::endl;
            StartWrite(&note);
            notes_iterator_++;
          } else {
            StartWritesDone();
          }
        }
        ClientContext context_;
        const std::vector<RouteNote> notes_;
        std::vector<RouteNote>::const_iterator notes_iterator_;
        RouteNote server_note_;
        std::mutex mu_;
        std::condition_variable cv_;
        Status status_;
        bool done_ = false;
      };
  
      Chatter chatter(stub_.get());
      Status status = chatter.Await();
      if (!status.ok()) {
        std::cout << "RouteChat rpc failed." << std::endl;
      }
    }
  
   private:  
  
    const float kCoordFactor_ = 10000000.0;
    std::unique_ptr<RouteGuide::Stub> stub_;
    std::vector<Feature> feature_list_;
  };
  
  int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // Expect only arg: --db_path=path/to/route_guide_db.json.
    std::string db = routeguide::GetDbFileContent(argc, argv);
    RouteGuideClient guide(
        grpc::CreateChannel("localhost:50051",
                            grpc::InsecureChannelCredentials()),
        db);
  
    std::cout << "-------------- RouteChat --------------" << std::endl;
    guide.RouteChat();
  
    return 0;
  }
```

The crash point:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found that on a server side the mutex mu is locking only the received_notes. But the to_send_notes are not locked and get accessed from different functions, that are called by bidirectional core from different threads.
Slight modification of code made the server stable! (see how I placed the mutext lock).

```
     #include <algorithm>
     #include <chrono>
     #include <cmath>
     #include <iostream>
     #include <memory>
     #include <string>
     #include <thread>
     
     #include "helper.h"
     
     #include <grpc/grpc.h>
     #include <grpcpp/security/server_credentials.h>
     #include <grpcpp/server.h>
     #include <grpcpp/server_builder.h>
     #include <grpcpp/server_context.h>
     #ifdef BAZEL_BUILD
     #include "examples/protos/route_guide.grpc.pb.h"
     #else
     #include "route_guide.grpc.pb.h"
     #endif
     
     using grpc::CallbackServerContext;
     using grpc::Server;
     using grpc::ServerBuilder;
     using grpc::Status;
     using routeguide::Feature;
     using routeguide::Point;
     using routeguide::Rectangle;
     using routeguide::RouteGuide;
     using routeguide::RouteNote;
     using routeguide::RouteSummary;
     using std::chrono::system_clock;
     
     class RouteGuideImpl final : public RouteGuide::CallbackService {
      public:
       explicit RouteGuideImpl(const std::string& db) {
         routeguide::ParseDb(db, &feature_list_);
       }
     
       grpc::ServerBidiReactor<RouteNote, RouteNote>* RouteChat(
           CallbackServerContext* context) override {
         class Chatter : public grpc::ServerBidiReactor<RouteNote, RouteNote> {
          public:
           Chatter(absl::Mutex* mu, std::vector<RouteNote>* received_notes)
               : mu_(mu), received_notes_(received_notes) {
             StartRead(&note_);
           }
     
           void OnDone() override { delete this; }
           void OnReadDone(bool ok) override 
           {
             if (ok) 
             {
               // Unlike the other example in this directory that's not using
               // the reactor pattern, we can't grab a local lock to secure the
               // access to the notes vector, because the reactor will most likely
               // make us jump threads, so we'll have to use a different locking
               // strategy. We'll grab the lock locally to build a copy of the
               // list of nodes we're going to send, then we'll grab the lock
               // again to append the received note to the existing vector.
               mu_->Lock();
               std::copy_if(received_notes_->begin(), received_notes_->end(),
                            std::back_inserter(to_send_notes_),
                            [this](const RouteNote& note) {
                              return note.location().latitude() ==
                                         note_.location().latitude() &&
                                     note.location().longitude() ==
                                         note_.location().longitude();
                            });          
               notes_iterator_ = to_send_notes_.begin();
               mu_->Unlock();
               NextWrite();
             } else {
               //std::cout << "some client finished" << std::endl;
               Finish(Status::OK);
             }
           }
           void OnWriteDone(bool ok) override 
           { 
             if (ok)
             {
               NextWrite(); 
             }
             else
             {
               std::cout << "some client finished write" << std::endl;
               Finish(Status::OK);
             }
           }
     
          private:
           void NextWrite() 
           {
             mu_->Lock();
             if (notes_iterator_ != to_send_notes_.end()) {
               StartWrite(&*notes_iterator_);
               notes_iterator_++;
             } else {          
               received_notes_->push_back(note_);          
               StartRead(&note_);
             }
             mu_->Unlock();
           }
           RouteNote note_;
           absl::Mutex* mu_;
           std::vector<RouteNote>* received_notes_;
           std::vector<RouteNote> to_send_notes_;
           std::vector<RouteNote>::iterator notes_iterator_;
         };
         return new Chatter(&mu_, &received_notes_);
       }
     
      private:
       std::vector<Feature> feature_list_;
       absl::Mutex mu_;
       std::vector<RouteNote> received_notes_ ABSL_GUARDED_BY(mu_);
     };
     
     void RunServer(const std::string& db_path) {
       std::string server_address("0.0.0.0:50051");
       RouteGuideImpl service(db_path);
     
       ServerBuilder builder;
       builder.AddListeningPort(server_address, grpc::InsecureServerCredentials());
       builder.RegisterService(&service);
       std::unique_ptr<Server> server(builder.BuildAndStart());
       std::cout << "Server listening on " << server_address << std::endl;
       server->Wait();
     }
     
     int main(int argc, char** argv) {
       // Expect only arg: --db_path=path/to/route_guide_db.json.
       std::string db = routeguide::GetDbFileContent(argc, argv);
       RunServer(db);
     
       return 0;
     }
```

Problem is still on client side - sometimes it crashes. I had a look in the source, but did not find anything strange. So the question is still open about the route_guide_callback_client.cc